# How do I uninstall AVBIN on Mac?

Tags: macos

How do I uninstall AVBIN on Mac? I've looked every where on the web to find my answer. By the way I want it uninstalled so I can use pyglet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no official uninstall, so we need to discover it.

```
pkgutil --pkgs
```

Then you search for avbin, I found: com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg. A better way of searching:

```
pkgutil --pkgs | grep avbin
```

Now you can do

```
pkgutil --pkg-info com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg
```

You should get this:

```
package-id: com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg
version: 10
volume: /
location: usr/local/lib
install-time: <time>
```

Then cd to the install location.

```
cd /usr/local/lib
```

And list the packages files.

```
pkgutil --files com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg
```

This gives:

```
._libavbin.10.dylib
libavbin.10.dylib
```

So now we can do

```
sudo rm ._libavbin.10.dylib 
sudo rm libavbin.10.dylib
```

You will need to enter password. If you want to be 100% sure, then you can do:

```
sudo rm *libavbin*
```

That will delete everything with libavbin in it (In the folder you are, /usr/local/lib)

And finaly

```
sudo pkgutil --forget com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg
```

It should give:

```
Forgot package 'com.github.avbin.avbin10.libavbin.10.pkg' on '/'.
```